# Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском, если есть на английском?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, миграция, нытьё

Давайте обсудим здесь необходимость в Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Почему ХэшКод должен стать Stack Overflow на русском?
2. Почему ХэшКод не может остаться ХэшКод'ом?
3. Принесет ли это какие-нибудь плоды?
4. и т. п.

Comment: [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/173/23044)

Comment: @jfs, ТС туда изначально и запостил свою речь.

Comment: @Nofate: я не пометил как дубликат, а ссылка полезна, чтобы не повторяться.

Comment: Я опять не нужен, какая жалость. Что же мне теперь делать? Придумал, пойду выпью *кофе с сигареткой* и всплакну над этой ужасной проблемой в уголке комнаты, как духовно богатая дева.

Comment: @igumnov be nice. Вопрос полезный (я уверен у многих он возникает). И ответы могут быть интересными, например, я пока ещё не видел ответа, который сам бы хотел дать.

Comment: @jfs Stack Overflow на русском это не баг, а фича такая. P.S. На этом форуме я отыгрываю ленивого lawful evil персонажа.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Pisarik Не знаю что думает администрация в лице @NicolasChabanovsky по этомоу поводу, но лично мне весь этот ваш тезис снизу просто кажется нелогичной унылой писаниной в стиле %sitename% не нужен.

1. То что вы считаете английский язык международным не отменяет того факта что на русском говорит 140.000.000 человек живущих в стране. Мне например он(английский) совсем не нравится, т.к. совершенно невыразителен, постоянно к месту и не месту используется в деловом общении и им пользуются слишком много людей. Русский, французский или японский гораздо более выразительны, десу.
2. Количество и качество русского IT сообщества, одним из представителей которого является ruSO в целом не так уж и плохо (могло быть гораздо, гораздо хуже) из-за мощной системы технического образования доставшейся в наследство от союза и развития компьютерных сетей за последнее время.
3. Если вопрос действительно сложный, нетривиальный и представляет практический интерес его просто заплюсуют и рано или поздно найдется человек с ответом.
4. Количество вопросов и число участников не имеет большого значения. В конце концов здесь собираются для того чтобы на них отвечать, а не мерить сколько их всего болтается в базе.
5. По поводу переезда, то новый движок очевидно лучше чем старый ХэшКодовский Django. По крайней мере из-за очередей правок. Зачем тратить время на то чтобы переписывать его самостоятельно, если можно просто сэкономить и лицензировать уже готовый и оттестированный?

Короче говоря ruSO конечно не свободен от недостатков (низкой скорости постинга, студентов с просьбами сделать лабу, почему PHP опять не работает и.т.д.), но если закрыть на это глаза то остается вполне себе годное программистское сообщество/коллективно редактируемый справочник, которое **нужно и лучше чем ничего.**

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, что Вы сумели изменить мое мнение в другую сторону.

Comment: Сам я немного идеалист. Поэтому сразу же задумался о дублировании информации с enSO на ruSO, причем не средствами перевода, а по средствам нового наполнения. Этот способ создания русской базы знаний кажется довольно тернистым, т.к. то что имеется никак не используется.

Comment: @pisarik Не за что, в итоге зло опять победило бобро.  И да, не стоит идеализировать enSO, ни вообще какие-либо отдельные источники с технической документацией, а лучше верить своим глазам и общей картине, которая получается при прочтении нескольких авторов.

Answer (score 17):

Давайте разберём ваши вопросы.

1. Почему ХэшКод должен стать Stack Overflow на русском?

   Фактически, хэшкод не *стал* Stack Overflow на русском. Stack Overflow *открыл* свой русскоязычный филиал как часть обычного процесса. Смотрите это [предложение на Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian). Stack Overflow на русском лишь унаследовал базу вопросов и пользователей ХэшКода, по доброй воле и договорённости между SO и участниками community.
2. Почему ХэшКод не может остаться ХэшКод'ом?

   Это пожелание сообщества. *Мы* согласились с предложением SO на слияние баз.
3. Принесет ли это какие-нибудь плоды?

   Да, уже приносит.

   - Количество вопросов резко возросло по сравнению с ХК
   - Пришли новые, хорошие, полезные участники
   - Улучшилось удобство использования сайтом по сравнению со старым движком ХК.

   Это — реальные результаты, видимые всего лишь за один месяц. Думаю, в будущем таких результатов будет ещё больше.
4. И т. п.

   Несмотря на то, что программисту *очень желательно* владеть английским языком как лидирующим языком IT-отрасли, общение и обсуждение вопросов вовсе не обязано вестить на английском. Те, кто хочет общаться на английском, уже имеет английский SO. Те же, для кого русский язык является предпочтительным, и те, кого интересуют проблемы, типичные для русскоязычного пространства, имеют право на свои предпочтения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, сейчас перечитал и понял, что почему-то к этому новшеству я слишком резко отнесся. Наверное меня больше всего испугало то, что люди теперь будут двигаться по пути наименьшего сопротивления и задавать вопросы на русском SO (+ еще негативный опыт со всяких русских форумов, где все превращается во флуд). И со временем все только и будут здесь общаться, а про английский SO забудут. Переход на новую платформу - это хорошо, но вот такая, казалось бы, мелочь - переименование Hascode в русский SO вызвало бурный протест:) Название же могло старым остаться.

Comment: Насчёт флуда, покамест очень хорошо работают модераторы. За что им отдельное спасибо.

Comment: @pisarik: к сожалению или к счастью, но открытие SO на русском не привело к заметному падению трафика на основной SO. Думаю, про него не забудут. Что касается превращения во флуд — с этим всё очень хорошо, в движке SO хорошая налаженная система вычищения флуда (да и на ХК была аналогичная вроде как).

Answer (score 14):

Я отвечу лично за себя, как участник сообщества еще со времен ХэшКод.

**Что я приобрел от переезда**

Раньше был ХэшКод и все его постоянные участники хотели плюшек: чат, ajax на страницах и прочие удобные мелочи, которые есть в движке SO.
Мне без разницы, как называется сообщество- ХэшКод или русский СО. Это не принципиально. Теперь у меня есть сообщество_ХэшКод+новые_лица и удобные плюшки от движка СО.

**Что я потерял**
В-принципе можно считать потерей то, что приятно было ощущать себя модератором на сайте, но в последнее время у меня мало времени на досуг, поэтому от должности модератора на СО я отказался.
Но я не считаю это потерей, потому что движок СО дает возможность осуществлять базовые функции модерирования рядовым пользователям, а модераторам достается самая рутинная работа, так что не страшно :)

Answer (score 10):

Давайте рассмотрим ваши вопросы...

1. ХэшКод стал Stack Overflow на русском, потому что за счёт этого он приобретает мощный и удобный движок, продвижение за счёт старшего брата, увеличение аудитории, вовлечение пользователей в модерацию и прочие плюшки, при этом ничего полезного не теряя.
2. ХэшКод не может оставаться ХэшКодом, потому что ему нравятся мощный и удобный движок, продвижение за счёт старшего брата, увеличение аудитории, вовлечение пользователей в модерацию и прочие плюшки.
3. Плоды переезд уже принёс: мощный и удобный движок, продвижение за счёт старшего брата, увеличение аудитории, вовлечение пользователей в модерацию и прочие плюшки.

...у меня чувство, что я повторяюсь.

---

А вы кто вообще будете? Странно видеть подобный разнос от пользователя с 34 репы на СО и 27 репы на СО.РУ и с десятком вопросов на каждом сайте. Это не личный наезд, это вопрос опыта использования сайтов.

Просматривая ваш список вопросов на большом СО, можно заметить, что вам имеет смысл задавать вопросы там, но не потому что ваши вопросы какие-то супер-сложные, а потому что вы используете провалившийся JavaFX, который не завоевал популярности, и на СО.РУ шансы найти специалистов по нему, соответственно, невелики.

На СО.РУ вопросы у вас не запредельно сложные, вам тут на них без проблем отвечали.

Собственно, само деление на "тривиальные вопросы от школьников" и "убер-сложные вопросы от убер-крутых специалистов" в корне неверное. А где всё остальное-то? Отвечают обычно середнячки на вопросы середнячков, просто кто-то в чём-то разбирается лучше.

Ну да, на СО.РУ не обитают звёзды типа авторов популярных книг, разработчиков мейнстримовых языков и распространённых библиотек и т. п. Но я больше страдаю не из-за этого, а из-за того, что количество вопросов по интересующей меня тематике невелико. И вот эта проблема как раз решаемая, просто Stack Exchange надо приложить больше усилий к продвижению сайта, ведь количество русскоговорящих на большом СО огромно.

---

Отдельно выскажусь про международный английский. Во-первых, я абсолютно согласен, что в западном мире лингва франка — это английский язык, без вариантов.

@Vlad тут скинул ссылку на Википедию, где приведён список языков, отсортированный по количеству говорящих. Но — где карта, Билли? Нам нужна карта! А на карте прекрасно видно, что остальные языки заныканы по отдельным островочкам, а английский захватил весь развитый мир. Английским языком пользуются профессионалы из всех стран, это язык науки и торговли.

Смотреть надо сюда: [World language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_language).

Я вообще глобалист. Единый язык для все планеты — это то, что нужно для всеобщего счастья. Весь зоопарк языков должен умереть. А какой язык останется — мне никакого дела нет. Главное, чтобы был один.

К сожалению, при нашей жизни этого не произойдёт. Ещё несколько веков минимум потребуется.

А посему в SO.RU смысл есть.

Comment: К слову о переходе на мою личность: вы же знаете, что чем меньше шавка, тем больше от нее грохота. Я в общем-то и написал в своем ответе, что не являюсь профессионалом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь думаю, что SO.RU действительно имеет место быть.

Comment: @Discord: Ну, 2 с лишним миллиарда китайцев и индусов уже составляют более трети населения планеты. Это насчёт карты.

Comment: @VladD Никому нет дела до китайцев, пока они сидят в Китае. Когда китайцы обсуждают на международной научной концеренции новейшие открытия, они делают это на английском. Когда китайцы договариваются с партнёрами из других стран о производстве и поставке оборудования, они делают это на английском. Китайский на западе учит статистическая погрешность. Сила не в числе.

Comment: @Discord: На международной конференции — да. Но дома они это же обсуждают на китайском. В западном, европоцентрическом мире английский действительно международный. Но в Юго-Восточной Азии его роль вполне делят мандарин и японский. В арабском мире ну вы понели.

Comment: @VladD Временное явление. Несмотря на соизмеримые экономики Штатов и Китая, китайский явно не движется к захвату мира. Сравните количество американцев, которые учат китайский, и китайцев, которые учат английский. Ну и обе экономики стагнируют, радикальных перемен ждать не стоит. Скажем так, у китайского есть хорошие шансы стать *последним* мёртвым языком. :)

Comment: @Discord: А арабский? Хе-хе. Экономика-шмекономика, пассионарность всё заруливает :)

Comment: @Discord, английский это тоже временное явление. Единого языка не было и никогда не будет.

Comment: @ixSci [World’s Languages Dying Off Rapidly](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/09/18/world/18cnd-language.html?_r=0)

Comment: @Discord, ну и что? За всю историю человечества много языков умерло, много и родилось. Это не отменяет того факта, что никакого мирового языка нет и предпосылок к его появлению нет. Есть временные "победители", которые меняются от века к веку. Английский ничем не лучше, чем был французский. Посмотрим, что будет дальше.

Comment: @ixSci В любом случае это произойдёт (если произойдёт) не при нашей жизни. Так что не актуально.

Comment: Добавлю свое слоупочное мнение по поводу языков: это же процесс непрерывной мутации и эволюции. Когда-то был рацсвет Рима, и в отдельно взятой Европе латынь была на правах мирового языка. В результате во всех сегодняшних европейских языках существенная доля корней заимствована из латыни. Думаю, единый язык когда-нибудь будет. Но он точно не будет сегодняшним английским, китайским или каким-то еще. Он будет, вероятно, похож на английский, китайский и что-нибудь ещё.