# Зачем нужен StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Зашёл на ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help - по ней не очевидно зачем.

Как я понимаю - за тем что бы собрать баги, или неочевидные методы в программировании в справке формата вопрос-ответ. Или курса у форума нет, главное помощь людям?

В правилах, в принципе сказано что домашнее задание допустимо. И похоже.. началась сессия [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Если работа за автора понятна... всётаки, есть ли:

- ccылка для спрашивающего, где разъясняется каким должен быть и не должен быть вопрос, зачем и какого типа должны быть вопросы? База знаний - какого рода знания здесь собраны?
- ccылка для отвечающего, где разъясняется каким должен быть или не должен быть ответ? Пожалуй... если в ответе есть спорные моменты, например сделано 50% задания как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841092/17974). Допустимы ли "недоделаные" ответы при наличии полного ответа где очевидно что доделать его не так то просто, или такие ответы закрывать тревогами? Или пусть болтается - всёравно никто не проголосует за? И степень очевидности... как её определить...

Comment: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @AK теперь вижу, кнопка ещё и в конце списка расположена. Не видел раньше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском, если есть на английском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @Grundy как минимум я не englishspeaker, и таких думаю много.

Comment: На мой взгляд -- помогать людям. (но тут может быть столько же мнений, сколько участников)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ccылка для спрашивающего, где разъясняется каким должен быть и не должен быть
> вопрос, зачем и какого типа должны быть вопросы?

#### [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

- [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> ccылка для отвечающего, где разъясняется каким должен быть или не должен быть ответ?

#### [Как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

- [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

> База знаний - какого рода знания здесь собраны?

На которые был спрос и предложение. То есть, для вопросов, к которым нашлись отвечающие. Определяющий фактор для всей этой системы — **на какие вопросы отвечают**. Не номинально, по факту публикации ответа, а так, чтобы для ТСа поднятая в вопросе проблема была решена.

И вокруг этого слабоопределённого множества вопросов формируется всё остальное.

- Правила пытаются грубо определить это множество вопросов и проинформировать о сложившейся практике все стороны взаимодействия.
- Механизмы голосов и закрывашек помогают авторам вопросов готовить вопросы, на которые с большей вероятностью ответят.
- Ограниченная тематика и метки помогают отвечающим находить вопросы из этого множества без микроскопа и тонн терпения.

И так далее.

---

> Допустимы ли "недоделаные" ответы при наличии полного ответа где очевидно что доделать его не так то просто, или такие ответы закрывать тревогами?  Или пусть болтается - всёравно никто не проголосует за? И степень очевидности... как её определить...

Да, допустимы. Ведь:

> Ответы, которые **совершенно не отвечают на вопрос**, могут быть удалены. Это относится к ответам, которые:
>
> - ...
> - даже частично не отвечают на фактический вопрос.
>
> <sub>[— "Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)</sub>

Ответ пытается ответить на вопрос — значит, годится. Если он отвечает не на весь вопрос, то проблема может быть как в ответе, так и в вопросе: либо вопрос слишком общий (закрыть вопрос), либо ответ плохой (заминусовать ответ). Тревоги на ответ в такой ситуации неуместны.

Как определить, достоин ли ответ минуса? Просто послушайте себя. Голоса являются выражением личного мнения о сообщении, никаких особых правил о том, куда их ставить можно, а куда нет — нету. В худшем случае, если система заподозрит серийное голосование, она аннулирует часть голосов, но вы сможете их вернуть обратно при желании.

Answer (score 10):

На английской мете есть [длинные дискуссии](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal) по этой теме.

Я так понял, оффициальная цель написана в [Тур по Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) ([англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)):

> С вами вместе мы создаем свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.

На английском SO:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Т.е. в первую очередь цель - не столько помогать задающим вопросы, сколько делать базу знаний по программированию для будущих читателей.

Answer (score 7):

## [Stack Overflow: None of Us is as Dumb as All of Us](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/)

> Зачем нужен Stack Overflow?

Чтобы не изобретать велосипедов без необходимости. Чтобы каждому с нуля  не решать типичные задачи каждый раз. Чтобы человек, имея конкретную техническую проблему, мог сделать запрос в гугле и приземлиться на странице с решением.

Подавляющее число повседневных задач программирования, системного администрирования компетентные люди могут решить самостоятельно. Но не найдётся ни одного человека, которые на все простые вопросы сможет ответить с тем фокусом, который может быть в Stack Overflow ответах. Даже в казалось бы тривиальных задачах типа: "вывести текст на экран" могут быть тонкости (представьте переносимый код, поддерживающий Unicode, цвета). [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/23044).

Задачу, на которую вы не можете себе позволить потратить более 15 минут на работе, мог кто-то подробно изучать: что может не иметь смысла для одного случая, но может быть оправданным, если решением смогут воспользоваться и другие люди многократно. К примеру, если часовые зоны не являются фокусом приложения, то часто код с датами содержит ошибки, которых легко избежать, имея небольшой опыт в этой тематике. За доступные 15 минут все тонкости тяжело усвоить, но за 15 минут можно понять Stack Overflow ответ по конкретной проблеме, написанный автором, который мог больше опыта именно по этой проблеме иметь (для него ответ тривиален). Для вас ответ на какой-то другой вопрос может быть крайне простым, но который требовал бы от других людей [неоправданного] времени на исследования.

Конкретных объективных метрик, определяющих что такое хороший вопрос/ответ тяжело найти. Основной критерий качества это полезность для людей из поисковика, которые пытаются найти ответ на их вопрос по тематике сайта: [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4181/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Общие рекомендации о том как вопрос/ответ создать есть в справке (иконка со знаком вопроса наверху): [/tour](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), [/help/how-to-ask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [/help/how-to-answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). О конкретных неясных моментах можно на Мете спросить (на текущем сайте).

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, что **цель** - извлечение прибыли, а остальное - все что написано камрадами, это миссия (то есть для чего существует):

> С вами вместе мы создаем свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.

Но все это вместе никак не отменяет цель SO - извлечение прибыли - [здесь большая дискуссия по-поводу бизнес модели SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model) - есть ссылки на финотчеты компании.

Comment: Прибыль у проэкта должна быть, иначе... сайт на сервере не сможет существовать. Хорошее замечание.

Comment: @nick_n_a некоммерческие проекты могут существовать, не принося прибыль. SO к ним, разумеется, не относится, но вот так вот обобщать не стоит.

Comment: Возможная цель, собирание наработок и бесплатный баг тестинг продуктов и технологий MS, для чего они и скупают OpenSource-aware ресурсы. Вероятнее всего в один прекрасный день все это будет похоронено, и зачищено.. как знать, время покажет, но тенденции не обманывают обычно :)

Answer (score 2):

Больная тема.
Сколько гигабайт текста переведено на споры о максимальной точной формулировке целей проекта в целом и работы за автора в частности.

На SO могут помочь тем, у кого проблема с пониманием решения какой-либо проблемы на IT-тематику.
Помощь по своему определению **со**действие автору.

Comment: Мне формулировка нравится. Осталось придумать на последний абзац формулировку. И... закрывать такие ответы тревогами, или пусть живут.

Comment: Если автор не приложил своих действий, то содействия не выйдет, так что закрыть! :)